# Rails 3 + Ajax: how to access my local form builder instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views, simple-form

I have a form that displays a set of inputs. I also have a button, and when clicked, I make an ajax request which is supposed to replace the existing inputs with a different set of inputs.

All my ajaxy linking stuff up works fine. The problem is that I'm using a `form_for`, so in order to display the new form inputs, I need the form builder instance.

#### View File

```
<%= simple_form_for @order do |f| %>
    <div id="info">
        <%= render 'my_first_form_fields_partial', f: f %>
    </div>
    <%= link_to 'Change inputs', change_inputs_path, remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

I'd like my js.erb to look like this, but `f` is only defined within the scope of the form in the view.

```
$('#info').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'my_second_fields_partial', f: f) %>");
```

How can I work it so that I can get `f` into that partial somehow?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Can you use fields_for in your partial, and pass the @object to it? That way you don't need to  pass a form builder?

partial:

```
<%= fields_for object do |f| %>
  f.text_field :field_name
<% end %>
```

```
$('#info').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'my_second_fields_partial', object: @object) %>
```

Comment: I edited my answer. Can you try `f.text_field` rather than `f.input`?

Comment: Such a simple solution, but so very effective. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @flyfish, his answer helped me solved how to do ajax with nested attributes. I took  @flynfish answer and tweeked it for my situation:

```
<%= fields_for object do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields nested_object, child_index: Time.now.to_i do |builder| %>
<% end %>
```

`$('#info').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'my_second_fields_partial', object: @object), nested_object: @nested_object %>`

The `child_index` is important for without it your params hash will build with [0] and will then overlay any other records built with the initial fields_for which starts at zero and increments from there.