# Rails 4 / Ruby 2: Local variable (FormBuilder) for partial is lost through dynamic update

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have this form that renders a partial for selecting a person's task.

**new.html.slim:**

```
= form_for(@person) do |f|
  = f.text_field :name
  = f.fields_for :assignment do |a|
    = a.collection_select :project_id, Project.order(:name), :id, :name
    div id="task_list"
      = render 'shared/_task_select', a: a
  = f.submit 'Save'
```

**shared/_task_select.html.slim:**

```
= a.collection_select :task_id, @tasks, :id, :name
```

Changing the project triggers a javascript that runs a "create_tasklist"-method in the PersonsController.

**new.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#person_assignment_attributes_project_id').change(function() {
        var selection = $('#person_assignment_attributes_project_id').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/create_tasklist",
            data: {
                project_id : selection
            },
            dataType: "script"
        });
    });
});
```

The "create_tasklist"-method triggers a javascript that updates the partial:

**create_tasklist.js.erb:**

```
$("#task_list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'shared/task_list', a: a) %>");
```

Now this raises the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `a' for #<#<Class:0x42cd770>:0x4213ef0>
```

The same form works well when editing existing persons - until changing the project. Thus, FormBuilder "a" loses its definition through the javascript actions. I have to use a partial here because I want to do more stuff with it in a later stage. Any ideas how to get that variable to keep its defintion?

**Edit 1:**
I already tried adding this below the third line of new.html.slim:

```
 javascript:
   var a = "#{a}";
```

and then adding: `a: a` in the "data" declaration of new.js.
**Edit 2:**
With this the FormBuilder seems to pass through until the "create_tasklist"-method, but I do not know how to access it properly there. If I declare ´@a = params[:a]´ in the "create_tasklist"-method and then use (in create_tasklist.js.erb):

```
$("#task_list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'shared/task_list', a: @a) %>");
```

I recieve the error:

```
 undefined method `collection_select' for "#&lt;ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x4760400&gt;":String
```

So the FormBuilder has become a string but a least it "got through" somehow. How can I leave it intact and is a more efficent way to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3 + Ajax: how to access my local form builder instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942576/rails-3-ajax-how-to-access-my-local-form-builder-instance)

Comment: How do you soppose your server-side local variables to "go through" AJAX request intact?

Comment: That problem is related but no duplicate: This is a nested form in which only a single field is supposed to be included in the partial. If I used the solution suggested in the other topic, I would still need to pass FormBuilder "f" to the partial in order to keep the nested structure.

Comment: why not `<%= fields_for :whatever { |a| escape_javascript(render 'shared/task_list', a: a) } %>` then ?

Comment: @m_x: This raises ´syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ')'´. I also think this would break the nesting, because it doesn't uses "f.fields" but "fields". And when using "f.fields", "f." would be undefined.

Comment: @Marek Lipka: That is indeed not very well put. What I mean is someway of passing the variable. Just as I tried with the additions I made to the code, which I described in the edits of my post.

Comment: duh, use `fields_for(:whatever){` ... I think you don't have a choice if you go this way. The point of `fields_for` is to generate appropriate input names (`person[assignment_attributes][task]`, for instance), so you can go with : `fields_for('person[assignment_attributes]', @assignment){|a|` ...

Comment: another way would be to instantiate the form builder yourself. You should dive into rails source to see how its done.